# Explanation of PCB specification

Tags: voltage, pcb, pcb-design, usb, layout

I'm using this IC - [USB5816 SS](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/00002238E.pdf)

In this application note, [Link](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN26.2-Application-Note-DS00001876C.pdf), page 7, it is given as,
"Consider laminates with low Df ratings at 10 GHz. These lower loss materials include FR408HR, FR408HRIS,
N4000-13SI, Rogers, Polyimide, etc. 370HR, NP-175 and IT-180 (or equivalent) with Df ratings of ~1.5 may usually be used for SS paths of 10 cm or less on carefully designed platforms."

Can someone tell me how to understand the Df?

Also, Can you explain what is "Df ratings of ~1.5"?
I see a number of 0.002 for Df for very good material.
I see a number of 0.02 for Df for a typical material.
I will say Df at 1.5 is actually very high, instead of low.

Please clarify

Comment: It does not make any sense. It might be an error in the application note. Maybe the number is wrong, or they are not actually talking about the Df itself but some other unit that is derived from it and have just forgotten the units. Ask Microchip.

Comment: What Df ratings are unacceptable?